# How to make a mask with a table of contents with slidify?

Tags: r, r-markdown, slidify

I am very interested by this userfriendly alternative to Latex for beautiful [presentations](http://slidify.org/samples/intro/#1), but I think that when a presentation is long, it is userful to add a mask to the slides with the full plan and where we are in it ([example of a discreet one in Beamer](http://www.google.fr/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FCp1zt.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Ftex.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F28654%2Fbeamer-table-of-contents-display-all-subsections-below-section&h=686&w=902&tbnid=U7dtU04iTco8DM%3A&docid=ndBSHNeZhTqcbM&ei=Dr3yVdqtCujU7AbCjqHgDw&tbm=isch&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=488&page=1&start=0&ndsp=26&ved=0CCQQrQMwAWoVChMI2uyFqvLuxwIVaCrbCh1CRwj8)).

I am using the io2012 style with slidify.

Is it possible to do this with slidify ? I haven't been able to find a single example but maybe I am not using the proper key words.